# !=null (в java)

Tags: java

Начал изучать яву, возник маленький вопрос: при использовании конструкции "<выражение>!=null" обнаруживается ошибка, как ее обойти? Это мне необходимо для проверки -  не было ли присвоено значение переменной с момента ее объявления.

**Заранее спасибо!**

Comment: таких ошибок очень легко избежать если пользоватся IDE (средой разработки), например, - Eclipse

Comment: @jmu Но ведь в этом так мало эпическго героизма, не так ли?  :)

Comment: ОМГ, я писал и пишу в IDE. С чего вы взяли обратное?

Comment: С того, что все IDE подсвечивают красным эту ошибку.

Comment: Я писал: "обнаруживается ошибка". Ни слова не было сказано, что это ошибка выполнения. Вы, сударь, тролль видимо.

Comment: А вы, сударь, читать не умеете. Что же мне теперь, обзываться?

Comment: С чего подобный вывод? Что именно я пропустил в нашем диалоге?

Comment: Ну вот, влип. С того, что если бы вы прочли внимательно текст обнаруженной ошибки, то вопрос бы не возник. Текст ошибки ясно указывает на причину, а решение возникает сразу по прочтении ошибки.

Comment: Именно поэтому я спросил насчет альтернативного метода проверки выполнения инициализации переменных простого типа. Полный ответ на вопрос получил в посте yozh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Локальные переменные сразу после объявления имеют неопределенное значение (не `null` для ссылочных типов, как это происходит с переменными класса, а просто неопределенное). При попытке использовать (например, как вы в сравнении с `null`) локальную переменную до ее инициализации компилятор выведет ошибку типа "might not be initialized". Чтобы этого избежать можно, например, при объявлении сразу инициализировать ссылку `null`'ом:

```
Object o = null;
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы ссылочный тип проверяете, или примитивный, например int? Если примитивный, то null там не имеет смысла никакого, все примитивные объекты инициализируются по умолчанию, оттуда и ошибка.
Если ссылочный, то код надо посмотреть и конкретную ошибку.

Comment: Интересно, а как вы собрались проверять примитивный тип на null? В Java только объекты можно проверить на отсутствие ссылки.

Comment: я и говорю что это чушь полная, просто слово <выражение> и отсутствие контекста в вопросе рождает в голове возможные случаи и ошибки. Тут вопрос просто точнее надо задавать.

Comment: Это еще нормально, от людей, которые вообще не знают что такое программирование и не такое услышишь.

Comment: Во многих языках программирования значение null у переменных элементарного типа означает отсутствие инициализации их. К примеру в php указанная мной конструкция будет работать.

Comment: Ваше сравнение неуместно. В интерпретируемых языках всегда есть ссылка(даже для примитивных типов как например в Питон), в отличие от компилируемых(в С++, Java), где примитивные типы не имеют ссылок и хранятся в стеке. Кроме того, вопрос именно по Java. 
Разные языки - разные примочки.